# Range of trace map notation

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

regarding the range of the trace map $\gamma : H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega) $ where $\Omega$ is an open set of $ \mathbb{R}^n$, What motivates or justifies the notation : $ H^{\tfrac 12}(\Omega)$ of the range of $\gamma$ i.e $ \Im(\gamma)$ ? (the $\frac 12$)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/347250/8157)